# Remove comments in Laravel Blade view

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to remove all HTML comments from a Blade view. I found this link on the internet but the solution doesn't seem to work anymore in Laravel 5.2 / 5.3

https://gist.github.com/Ranerg/7427126

Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Remove them from the blade file? Seems unnecessary to run the templates through yet another parser (blade parses the template file as well) before sending it to the browser. If you really need comments, add them as PHP-comments instead. Then they will be removed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use a lot of html comments <!-- blahbla --> in my blade files. I would like to see these comments removed when the file is sent to the browser. The comments uglify my html code when I take a look at it with Firebug, making it harder to read/edit it under water.

Answer (score 7):

The easy way is using Blade comments instead of HTML comments, you are indeed using blade, so, why use other kind of comments?

Blade comments:

```
{{-- This comment will not be present in the rendered HTML --}}
```

Now, if you insists on removing HTML comments, you could actually do some minification of the HTML at the same time.
You could do a Middleware that process the output and remove comments, remove spaces, and other stuffs.

Take a look at this solution: https://asked.io/laravel-5-minify-middleware

And maybe just include a pattern matching like this `'/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',` to the list of replacements and that should work.
Or you could actually search for a minification library and use it in that middleware.

Do notice that this process adds a little of overhead, not much actually, but some.

The best and more efficient solution to just remove the comments would be to use Blade comments.